# How to delete the apex classes using ant migration tool

Tags: community, deployment

I want to delete apex class from ant tool. i configure

```
<target name="undeployCode" depends="proxy">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username_DEV}" password="${sf.password_DEV}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl_DEV}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="removecodepkg"/>
</target>
```

and i created destructiveChanges.xml, package.xml in remove folder.

The destructiveChanges.xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>AbstrctClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>

    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

and package.xml is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
        <members>AbstrctClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>

         <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

but i am not able to delete the class. when run the operation it is saying success. but did not achieve that. can any one help on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncomfortable using the ANT tool (it can be tricky to pick up!) then you can always use third party software to do it. I work for Gearset and you should be able to use our thirty day trial to do that deletion in a few minutes.

[Link](https://gearset.com)

Answer (score 0):

This [Deleting Files from an Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm) documentation says:

> To deploy the destructive changes, you must also have a package.xml
>   file that lists no components to deploy, includes the API version, and
>   is in the same directory as destructiveChanges.xml

So remove the types from your package.xml and try again.

(You can also try using Ant's `-v` argument to get verbose debug output that might point you to the problem.)

Comment: @ Keith C    i did that. i kept booth the files and trying to remove the class. but it is not deleting. i checked in booth dev org ans sanbox. booth are failed.

Comment: @SFDCSrini OK, if that didn't work and apart from treble checking the class name and trying the -v I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you are struggling to do this with the manual `package.xml` and `destructiveChanges.xml` creation, you could use a third party tool like mine (Gearset)[https://gearset.com] that will automate this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>AbstrctClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>

    <version>33.0</version>
</Package> 

save as destructiveChanges.xml in removecodepkg folder

and 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

         <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

save as package.Xml in removecodepkg folder.

and use command:- ant undeployCode

Plz mark as best answer if it solves your problem. Thanks